# How do I create a custom Salesforce field to show units based on product family?

Tags: salesforce, report

I need to show the number of units for a product type in my reports.  I'm using a custom formula and this is what I have so far:

IF(ISPICKVAL( Family ,"Specific Product Category"),1,0) * Units_c

the syntax seems to work until I * units_c

Comment: I don't have the bucket enabled version.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You need to build the custom field within an object that contains both fields.

IF(ISPICKVAL( Product_Type__c ,"Product Type Name"), Unit_Count__c ,0)

It states; IF this pickvalue is this product name, then show it's unit count, if not, 0.